# How to enter an array formula on ethercalc.org

Tags: ethercalc

I added the following constants

```
+---+---+---+
|   | A | B |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
```

Then on C1 I wrote the following formula

```
=A1:A3+B1:B3
```

The result was

> Formula results in range value: A1:A3

On Google Sheets I could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and it automatically puts the formula as argument of ArrayFormula function. On Excel it's required to first select the required area for the result, write the formula, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Does [ethercalc.org](https://ethercalc.org/) supports arrays formulas? How are they used?

## References

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) Google Docs Editors Help
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) Google Docs Editors Help
- [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) Microsoft Support
- [Non-Scalar Evaluation (aka 'Array expressions')](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part2.html#__RefHeading__1017866_715980110) Oasis Open Document Part 2: Recalculated Formula (OpenFormula) Format

Comment: do your mean https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275

Comment: @eddyparkinson: Yes, but no limited too it. I added some several references to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMMAND() or DSUM() are maybe the closest.

But no, there is no arrayformula support yet.

- COMMAND() / COMMANDIF()

  These issue spreadsheet commands and can set cell values/colors. They can change anything on the sheet.

e.g. http://sheet.cellmaster.com.au/command_example

- DSUM() etc

  The database functions exist in ethercalc

> ```
>  DAVERAGE(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DCOUNT(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DCOUNTA(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DGET(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DMAX(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DMIN(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DPRODUCT(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DSTDEV(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DSTDEVP(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DSUM(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DVAR(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
>  DVARP(databaserange, fieldname, criteriarange)
> ```

ArrayFormula() docs https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275 
or 
=sum*{1,2;3,4})

Comment: The database functions are similar to SUM, AVERAGE, and other functions that allows a range as argument, but returns a Number. What I'm looking for is functions and/or formula notation to return an array.  I'll try COPYFORMULA / COPYVALUES

Comment: For examples of COPYVALUES see B67, for INSERT see B65 in http://sheet.cellmaster.com.au/carbonoffset/appeditor

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

At this time ethercalc.org doesn't handle array formulas like Excel or Google Sheets do but it has other functions like COPYVALUES, COPYFORMULAS, INSERT among others that could be used instead.

## Extended answer

From a [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100589/how-to-enter-an-array-formula-on-ethercalc-org/100667#comment87636_100616) by [eddiparkinson](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/38777/eddyparkinson)

> For examples of COPYVALUES see B67, for INSERT see B65 in http://sheet.cellmaster.com.au/carbonoffset/appeditor

From [userguide?](https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc/issues/274), notes mine:

> 1. where can I find the list of the functions (sqrt, sin, sum, ...)
>      accepted by ethercalc?
> 2. what is a waflphrase supposed to represent?
> 3. {...} Is it correct to say that certain formatting tags apply only to
>      multi-line texts? Such as ol, ul, .pre? Those with \n in their source
>      code's regexps?

---

> 1. `SocialCalc.Formula.FunctionList` — type that in the JS console of a running EtherCalc instance to get the full list. They are defined in
>      https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc/blob/master/formula1.js<sup>1</sup> and the
>      spec is OpenFormula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFormula
> 2. It's something like a Macro in the Socialtext system; currently EtherCalc does not implement WAFL expansion functionality.
> 3. Correct.

Notes:
<sup>1</sup>: The formula1.js file was removed from audreyt/ethecarlc/master. It's available on other branches but on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16329364/1595451) by [eddyparkingson](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/38777/eddyparkinson) refers to https://github.com/marcelklehr/socialcalc

## Ethercalc function guide

**Fx** toolbar button - the button on the spreadsheet toolbar gives a list of Ethercalc functions with descriptions.

## Ethercalc functions

[Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j6ZADQz72Dan8czPUbEUBGwP0K4DuUEmdlPRREAlx8s/edit?usp=sharing) with the list of functions returned by typing `SocialCalc.Formula.FunctionList` on the browser console while having a Ethercalc.org sheet open. There are 136 functions, those that I identified that are not included in the OpenFormula spec are bolded. Note that the functions that returns arrays like TRANSPOSE, OFFSET, MMULT, etc. are not included.